# Framing around PVC pipe

Tags: basement, framing

I'd like to frame a wall around a 3 inch PVC pipe in my basement and would like to lose as little interior space as possible. The picture shows what I'd like the framing to look like and the dimensions. It's not load bearing, it will just have drywall on it. The top section "A" is build with 2x4s sideways, sort of like a soffit/bulkhead ladder that's why the thickness is shown as 1 1/2".

Is there a way to make this rigid/stable without tying section "C" into concrete with tapcons through the insulation? Flat corner braces between A&B and B&C? Screws instead of nails? In g

Thanks in advance for any advice.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image: Corrected with suggestions]

Comment: That seems like a crazy amount of work for 3 inches, considering drywall or whatever. I'd much prefer a flat wall. Are you sure it's that important?

Answer (score 2):

Your pictures are perfect, except you need a Beta before the "A" - which is just a header to go across joists or blocking.   This will give you the stability.

For extra stability you can add a parallel header (Zeta) at the top on the same line as "C" and block Beta and Zeta - don't need a lot of blocking.   That's it.

And because I want you to do it right... I need to know your location... as the cavity for the PVC is more useful in some locations than others.

Based on last picture:

1. Bottom of top section 2x4 down slightly to fully align with blocking.
2. Flip top plate so flat part attaches.
3. Add a parallel 2x4 to top plate against wall.
4. Add a few blocks between two top plates.

This is about as sturdy as you can get.

Comment: "Beta" and "Zeta" - are those phonetic spelling for "B" and "Z", or are they some sort of technical term for blocking (or something) that I'm not familiar with?

Comment: @FreeMan  I agree with your comment completely, I also have no idea what those terms are.

Comment: @FreeMan - they are just different letters!   (what we tell people not in the illuminati)

Comment: I'm in Southern NH. I'm not familiar with these terms but I added another picture with more detail, it might already have what you called a Zeta? I imagine I'd need blocking between B pieces or to nail it to the face of A2 or something like that. The way I drew it does not seem like it would be very rigid and I'm sure there are best practices on how to do something like this but I just don't know what they are.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood 3&4 but I added a picture with the suggested corrections and showing the joists above the wall. Where would the parallel 2x4 and the blocking go? Thanks.

Comment: Yes that last picture looks good.   That whole top section should be packed with insulation unless you are in a warm climate.

Comment: Your only talking about an offset of  3 inches. Have you considered just making a straight wall?  +1 for the nice drawing. You could add more insulation then.

Comment: @BrianK - I agree that aesthetically one straight wall might look better.   You only put insulation in basement below grade in extremely cold climates - think colder than Chicago.

Comment: Thanks for the answers and suggestions. Definitely yes to insulation (I'm in New England). Yes I'm considering a straight wall, that would for sure make my life easier. But I'm trying to figure this out because I have two other sections where the savings will be over a foot because of how ducting is in the way. It's the same issue there in terms of framing.